# Static classes inheriting from abstract class in PHP

Tags: php, inheritance, static, factory, abstract

I have stumbled upon an interesting problem/bug that I eventually solved, but the solution is not what I expected or would like it to be.

The setup is simple. There is an abstract static class **Factory**, which has a reference to a singleton (**Registry**) as well as two static properties, **model** and **table**.

There are a number of static classes building upon/inheriting from this abstract class and they all have an **init()** method in which they set the **model** and **table** properties. Of course, since **model** and **table** are static they can only have one value which is the same for all the child classes of the abstract **Factory** class. This is the problem/bug.

However, my aim is to have each child class have its own **model** and **table** so I am forced to declare **model** and **table** in each child class as a static property. This seems a bit cumbersome (and not very DRY), but it seems to me that this is the only solution if I want to have (1) the classes inherit from the abstract **Factory** class and (2) remain static.

Is my assumption correct or is there another approach that I am missing?

Comment: please read : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you refer to this discussion about the singleton design pattern. Granted, singletons do have pros and cons, but the question at hand is about a specific use case of static classes inheriting from an abstract static class while sharing a set of identical properties. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal is to have different values for `$model` and `$table` in different static child classes?

Assuming that is the case, I don't see how You could possibly accomplish that without explicitly defining them different in each child class.

I don't think it is cumbersome. I see it as a good practice - by keeping functionality where it belongs.

Comment: That is correct. I assume that there is no other approach in this case. Cumbersome is probably a bad choice of words, but I try to write as DRY as possible. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @BartJacobs - DRY is even more beneficial when balanced with others, see [Real Ultimate Programming Power](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/02/real-ultimate-programming-power.html)